# javascript: major slowdown in if case

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple code that generates a table.

However, when i added 3 if lines, it became super slow. 
Anyone have any ideas why?

Code:

```
for (var i=0; i<=noofRows; i++){
  var rg = genguid();
  for (var j=1; j<=noofbackuprows; j++){
  to+='<tr>';
  to+='<td>'  + prefix + rg + '-' + j;      
  to+='</td>';      
  if (j<3){var vval = 10000};
  if (j=3){var vval = 5000};
  if (j>4){var vval = 2500};
  to+='<td>'  + vval + '</td>';          
  to+='</tr>';      
    }
}
```

Infringing lines:

```
  if (j<3){var vval = 10000};
  if (j=3){var vval = 5000};
  if (j>4){var vval = 2500};
```

If i remove the infringing lines, it works great.
What's going on?

Comment: `j=3` should be `j==3` or `j===3`.

Comment: For starters you should be using `else if`.

Comment: You could also remove one of those `if` statements and declare `var vval = 10000` just as the `for` loop begins. Then just use the last 2 conditionals and avoid one check. If those other 2 conditionals fail, then by default the value has to be 10000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with what you currently have:

```
if (j<3){var vval = 10000};
if (j=3){var vval = 5000};
if (j>4){var vval = 2500};
```

Firstly, `j = 3` assigns the value `3` to `j`. It doesn't check to see whether `j` is equal to `3`. To fix this, change this to `==` or `===`:

```
if (j === 3) { var vval = 5000; }
```

This is why your application is becoming slow, because your `for` loop is getting stuck in a loop as after a certain point `j` will always be equal to `3`.

Secondly, you should use `else if`, otherwise all three `if` statements will be checked even if the first one satisfied the requirement:

```
if (j < 3) { var vval = 10000 }
else if (j === 3) { var vval = 5000 }
else if (j > 4) { var vval = 2500 }
```

Also note that putting semicolons after the curly brackets on `if` statements is unnecessary, so I've removed those as well.

Comment: Sheesh, what a rookie mistake to make! Guess i need some rest... Thanks!

Comment: Bonus: none of your `if`s currently match the case where `j` is `4`. The last `if` checks if `j` is *strictly* greater than `4`, so a value of `4` won't do. You should probably change that last line to `else if (j > 3) { var vval = 2500 }` in order to cover all cases.

Comment: Yup, caught that after it ran for the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because in the loop you're setting `j=3` for evermore. I'm surprised this does not crash the browser entirely.

Use the equality operator `==` or strict equality operator `===`